# Docker - Unauthorized in MariaDB

Tags: docker

I want to create a simply LAMP with docker. The code is

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0.0-apache
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libzip-dev \
    && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
    
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

Docker Compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  www:
    build: .
    container_name: 'www'
    hostname: 'laravelvue.com'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks: 
      - default
    volumes: 
      - ./www:/var/www/html
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.7.1
    container_name: 'mariadb'
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: laravelvue
      MARIADB_USER: root
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: test
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    networks: 
      - default
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - database
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test 
    ports:
      - 8000:80
volumes:
  persistent:
```

When i launch `docker compose up -d` works, but when i try to enter in database (localhost:8000) with username *root* and password *test* returns

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
> getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

I´m new with docker so i don´t know exactly what´s is wrong ¿Anybody see what´s wrong?

Comment: `links:
      - database:db`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker networking works with the name of your service as hostname. So in your `database` service you can connect with your phpmyadmin via `http://phpmyadmin:8000`. The same is for the other services. In your phpadmin service you connect with your database via `http://database:3306`.

And remove the `networks: default` and `links: database` in your `docker-compose.yml` it is not needed, as you use version `3.8` in `docker-compose.yml`. And make sure your `phpadmin` service `depends_on` your `database` service.

Correct `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  www:
    build: .
    container_name: 'www'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes: 
      - ./www:/var/www/html

  database:
    image: mariadb:10.7.1
    container_name: 'mariadb'
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: laravelvue
      MARIADB_USER: root
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: test
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: test

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
     - database
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test 
    ports:
      - 8000:80
```

Comment: http://database:3306 returns DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Did you tried it from another container or from your host? From phpadmin you should be able to access the container via either: `docker exec -it phpmyadmin bash` or `docker exec -it phpmyadmin sh`. From there you can either use `curl` or `wget` to verify connection. From your hostmachine the database is exposed on `http://localhost:3306`. But from your phpmyadmin you cannot access your localhost on the hostmachine. So from the phpmyadmin machine there is nothing exposed on `http://localhost:3306`, instead you must use the docker networking way thus `http://database:3306`.

Comment: Mmm, i installed docker desktop, maybe this program doesn't have last version of docker compose.

Comment: If it works, could you mark the answer as answered?